# Arduino code to write and send at the same time simultaneously

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I am working a graphical blocks for Scilab (software similar to MATLAB) simulation environment. There should be blocks called AI (analogue input), AO, DO. Also, there will be two programs: 1) on the side of Scilab, one which sends and receives data; 2) on the side of Arduino, one which sends and receives data.

Right now I am working on Arduino side code. It, the code, should read voltage values from 6 inputs and sends them to Scilab via serial and simultaneously write 1/0 to its outputs when it gets data from Scilab. In my understanding, data sent/received should have information about pin number (to know what pin it should affect) and value itself. Also, it should read and receives at the same time.

Any ideas how I could do it? Help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [timer interrupt](http://letsmakerobots.com/node/28278) to read the values and send them via serial and handle the commands from Scilab in `loop()` as usual.

I'm not 100% sure whether there could be problems from possibly being interrupted while in `Serial.read()`. In this case you might have to disable interrupts while reading the request (check before with `Serial.available()` whether there's something to read).